# Saving user input in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to save data from user inputs in Spotfire? I mean, could I ask an user to provide an evaluation of a given report? Or could I save some other information like webbrowser, OS etc. in any way in the server?

Comment: You can write user input down to a file or the database. Is that what you mean? I would imagine with Javascript/JQuery that you could capture browser information as well. Some examples would help.

Comment: @MarkP., I need to collect an evaluation of Spotfire Reports' usefulness by their users (like a five-star scheme). However, I have limited access to server functionalities, due to security policies. I'd like to know more about either methods (writting to files/DB in Spotfire) in order to see which one is suitable for me.

Comment: Here is an article on writing back to databases : https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-write-back-database-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython-scripting

Answer (score 0):

You can use python script to append data to data table in spotfire.

Using copy and paste create a table in spotfire (with no values just headers) say two columns Rank and Comment. Then create a two document properties one for each column.

Add a button to run a append script to take your two document properties and append to your data table.

the python script would look like  :

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import AddRowsSettings
from System.IO import  StreamWriter, MemoryStream, SeekOrigin
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType, DataTableSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import TextFileDataSource, TextDataReaderSettings

x = Document.Properties['Rank']
y =Document.Properties['Comment']


print(x,y)

#Create some data with columns that match an existing table to which new rows need to be added. 
textData = "Rank,Comment,\r\n"+x+","+y+"\r\n" 
print(textData)

#Using a Memory Stream as a placeholder to write the columns to which can then be used to make a data source
stream = MemoryStream()
writer = StreamWriter(stream)
writer.Write(textData)
writer.Flush()
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

#Settings to tell the system the data types being imported.Here it is defined as a comma separated list of column index and their data types
readerSettings = TextDataReaderSettings()
readerSettings.Separator = ","
readerSettings.AddColumnNameRow(0)
readerSettings.SetDataType(0, DataType.String)
readerSettings.SetDataType(1, DataType.String)

textDataSource = TextFileDataSource(stream,readerSettings)

#Use settings here to automatically have the system match column names between the data table and the memory data source created above.
settings = AddRowsSettings(Document.ActiveDataTableReference,textDataSource)

#Add the rows from the datasource.
Document.ActiveDataTableReference.AddRows(textDataSource,settings)
```